# testng Parallel testing- avoiding class grouping

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, testng

I am trying to run tests in parallel using testng but I have some issues with my configuration.

I have a project with many class files, each containing many tests.

I am currently running tests using the parallel='methods' flag to maximize the number of tests running at a given time.

My goal is to avoid tests of the same class running at the same time while maximizing the number of parallel tests.

So given an example xml file:

```
<suite>
<test parallel='methods' thread-count=40>
    <classes>
    <class>Class1</class>
    <class>Class2</class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

And given 40 available threads, I would like to have 40 tests running at any given time.

I have used a method interceptor to randomize the test order and with eclipse debugger I know that is working correctly, and within each class the order can be controlled.

My goal is an execution like this:

```
<Test from class1>
<Test from class2>
<Test from class1>
<Test from class2>
```

But instead each class runs sequentially with their respective tests in parallel as below:

```
<Test from class1>
<Test from class1>
<Test from class2>
<Test from class2>
```

Class2 only starts executing when Class1 no longer has any tests to execute.

I have tried parallel='classes' but this gives 1 thread per class.

Is it possible to enforce a randomized order and maintain the amount of concurrent tests running?

I want to pass a list of randomized methods, and to queue up the execution to roughly follow that ordering.

I have tried breaking up the classes into separate suites and tests, however this does not meet the goal of 40 tests running in parallel as the classes have a different number of test methods in each one, and the run time of each test method is unknown.

My other thought was to combine classes using multiple inheritance, to combine the test methods of each class into 1 class, however java does not support multiple inheritance so that will not work.

Thank you to anyone reading this or providing advice or help.

Edit: Addressing possible duplicate:

The solution proposed in the other question will allow me to run classes in parallel with multiple threads, but if a test finishes before the others, it looks like the threads allocated for it will not be used.

I have more than 2 classes to parallelize, and if I start giving the threads to each test, I think i might run into issues- with 10 classes I would be limited to 4 threads each (total 40 in parallel). I might get stuck waiting on 1 test to complete running 4 methods at a time with 36 sitting idle, which probably negates any benefit from implementing this solution.

The ideal solution would have a common thread pool for the tests like with the basic single test/parallel='methods' approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallelizing classes and method in testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874072/parallelizing-classes-and-method-in-testng)

Comment: This method will allow me to run classes in parallel with multiple threads, but if a test finishes before the others, it looks like the threads allocated for it will not be used.

I have more than 2 classes to parallelize, and if I start giving the threads to each test, I think i might run into issues- with 10 classes I would be limited to 4 threads each (total 40 in parallel). 
 I might get stuck waiting on 1 test to complete running 4 methods at a time with 36 sitting idle. The ideal solution would have a common thread pool for the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `thread-count="40"` near the `parallel="methods"` attribute. Also give your classes with the package name if you did not.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the thread-count flag in my example pseudo-xml.

In my real xml file, I have it defined.

The tests in each class run in parallel without issue.

In the above example if class 1 and 2 both have 40 methods each, with 40 threads,
all methods in class1 start in parallel, finish, then all 40 methods in class2 start.

I would ideally like some way for class1 and class2 to execute in parallel, like the parallel='classes' flag, but with more threads.

Comment: Ok. I think your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874072/parallelizing-classes-and-method-in-testng.

Comment: Thank you. I may end up going that route with a compromise, but I am concerned that I will need to evenly split up the classes by the number of test methods, otherwise some tests may finish first and leave idle threads. Is there a way to ensure a common thread pool between the tests?
 I tried the solution provided with 40 threads at a suite level- but it started 2 tests with 40 threads each, 80 total- trying to run in parallel. 
I think i will have a problem with this method- trying to maximize the number of parallel classes executing but minimizing potential for idle threads.